# Solve from interpolation function

Tags: interpolation

I have the following list and its interpolating finction x1:

```
point={{0., 0.}, {0.2, 1.}, {0.25, 1.5}, {0.3, 1.}, {0.5, 0.}};x1 = 
Interpolation[point]
```

I would like to obtain values of x for which y=1 and I try:

```
Solve[x1[x] == 1, x]
```

but the output is:

```
NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions 
may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
{{InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.5}}, <>] -> 0.3}}
```

with a unique solution x=0.3. From the plot of x1, I expect that will be two different solutions. How can I solve this?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
FindRoot[x1[x] == 1, {x, .25, 0., 0.25}, Method -> "Secant"]
(*{x -> 0.2}*)
FindRoot[x1[x] == 1, {x, .25, 0.25, 0.5}, Method -> "Secant"]
(*{x -> 0.3}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numerical solver,

```
NSolve[x1[x] == 1, x]
```

> {{x -> 0.3}}

Comment: Usually `NDSolve`would be my first choice, but in this example I'm wondering why `NSolve[{x1[x] == 1, 0 <= x <= 0.5}, x]` doesn't evaluate the two(!) solutions.